# What can cause voltage irregularities across an IC chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, preamp

[image: This is the preamp section of one channel of a tape deck.]

This is the preamp section of a channel of a tape deck for which one channel is working and one is not.  Swapping all the components between the channels does not affect which channel is working correctly, so presumably the components are all functional.

Measuring the voltages across the IC chip on the good channel, the values are as in the schematic, while the values for the chip on the bad channel values are zero for pins one through five and around one for pins six and seven.

If there are no faulty components in a circuit, what else could cause voltage irregularities across an IC chip?

Comment: The chip itself is likely to be faulty.

Comment: I put the chip in a separate identical circuit and it worked so it doesn't seem to be faulty.

Comment: well then the circuitry around is clearly causing the problems, since you've precluded the IC.

Comment: Reveal the bad voltages you mentioned in your question please.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, and I asked this question to get a hint as to what specific circuitry around could be causing the problems.

Comment: can't tell you - everything.

Comment: @Andyaka question edited

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an adequate power feed to the chip (pin 7). Maybe link a data sheet?

Comment: https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/161498/TOSHIBA/TA7120P/894/3/TA7120P.html is the closest I can find.  Also maybe you could expand your guess into an answer; it seems it could be helpful.

Comment: Check if R27 is still in place with the correct value and the right voltage at teh other end of it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fault in the power distribution of the 12.9V dc supply.

Measure the voltage on that pin, with/without the IC and tracing to its source should pinpoint the fault.

measure Voltage on green trace and look for ~ 12V~13V.
[image]

It could be a cracked via.

[It's a vintage ssssssony](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiY7bGIy6DuAhUMZc0KHVlHBSAQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vintageshifi.com%2Frepertoire-pdf%2Fpdf%2Ftelecharge.php%3Fpdf%3DTechnics-RS-631-Service-Manual.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1lqaKwSTVfxMM48PMWKlN5)

Comment: Thank you much for the answer.  Not sure if it's too specific for the OP but it would be personally helpful if you could elaborate on how to trace to the source.

Comment: Follow the coloured trace road with a DMM and measure the voltage'

Comment: By the way, it's an rs-m22g; you were very close.